# Find difference between entryTime and exitTime from the MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem in retrieve the difference between EntryTime and ExitTime. I have a table named IOData and I am working on IOTime column.
The format of the table is:

```
HolderName        IODate        IOTime       IOGateName         IOStatus 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     00:50:05     Basement(I/O)        Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     00:52:55     Basement(I/O)        Exit 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     01:00:07     Basement(I/O)        Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     01:35:42     Basement(I/O)        Exit 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     01:36:37     Ground Floor(I/O)    Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     01:37:02     Ground Floor(I/O)    Exit 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     01:46:04     Ground Floor(I/O)    Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     01:46:29     Ground Floor(I/O)    Exit 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     01:47:02     Basement(I/O)        Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     04:09:11     Basement(I/O)        Exit 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     04:09:35     Ground Floor(I/O)    Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     04:11:27     Ground Floor(I/O)    Exit 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     04:11:54     Basement(I/O)        Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     05:10:28     Ground Floor(I/O)    Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     05:18:12     Main Door(I/O)       Exit 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     17:55:16     Main Door(I/O)       Entry 
Dinesh Kumar    2010/07/09     17:56:10     Ground Floor(I/O)    Entry
```

The problem is I have one column for taking difference of time. How can I overcome this Problem.
If I Break IOStatus in two column(Entry and Exit) then status entry can be less then exit or vice ver
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters you should combine IODate and IOTime into a single IODateTime field.  You've made this unnecessarily harder on yourself by splitting the date and time into two columns.  The jet db engine stores datetimes as floats with the decimal portion representing the time.  Calculating a time difference that spans more than one day will be a nightmare with your current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a view.

```
create view suspicious_person_movements as
select IO.holder_name,
cast(IO.io_date || ' ' || IO.io_time as timestamp) as io_timestamp,
-- Concatenate most recent earlier date and time, and cast to timestamp
cast((select max(io_date) 
      from iodata 
      where holder_name = IO.holder_name 
        and io_date <= IO.io_date) 
     || ' ' ||
     (select max(io_time)
      from iodata
      where holder_name = IO.holder_name 
        and io_date <= IO.io_date 
        and io_time < IO.io_time) as timestamp) as previous_timestamp,
-- Subtract the timestamps to get elapsed_time
cast(IO.io_date || ' ' || IO.io_time as timestamp) - 
cast((select max(io_date) 
      from iodata 
      where holder_name = IO.holder_name 
        and io_date <= IO.io_date) || ' ' ||
     (select max(io_time)
      from iodata
      where holder_name = IO.holder_name 
        and io_date <= IO.io_date 
        and io_time < IO.io_time) as timestamp) as elapsed_time,
IO.io_gate_name,
IO.io_status
from iodata IO
order by holder_name, io_date, io_time  -- Better to sort in the client?
```

Then I can just select all the rows from suspicious_person_movements. (Lightly edited to reduce horizontal scrolling.)

```
Dinesh 2010-07-09 00:50:05                                    Basement(I/O)   Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 00:52:55   2010-07-09 00:50:05   00:02:50   Basement(I/O)   Exit 
Dinesh 2010-07-09 01:00:07   2010-07-09 00:52:55   00:07:12   Basement(I/O)   Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 01:35:42   2010-07-09 01:00:07   00:35:35   Basement(I/O)   Exit 
Dinesh 2010-07-09 01:36:37   2010-07-09 01:35:42   00:00:55   Ground Fl(I/O)  Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 01:37:02   2010-07-09 01:36:37   00:00:25   Ground Fl(I/O)  Exit 
Dinesh 2010-07-09 01:46:04   2010-07-09 01:37:02   00:09:02   Ground Fl(I/O)  Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 01:46:29   2010-07-09 01:46:04   00:00:25   Ground Fl(I/O)  Exit 
Dinesh 2010-07-09 01:47:02   2010-07-09 01:46:29   00:00:33   Basement(I/O)   Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 04:09:11   2010-07-09 01:47:02   02:22:09   Basement(I/O)   Exit 
Dinesh 2010-07-09 04:09:35   2010-07-09 04:09:11   00:00:24   Ground Fl(I/O)  Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 04:11:27   2010-07-09 04:09:35   00:01:52   Ground Fl(I/O)  Exit 
Dinesh 2010-07-09 04:11:54   2010-07-09 04:11:27   00:00:27   Basement(I/O)   Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 05:10:28   2010-07-09 04:11:54   00:58:34   Ground Fl(I/O)  Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 05:18:12   2010-07-09 05:10:28   00:07:44   Main Door(I/O)  Exit 
Dinesh 2010-07-09 17:55:16   2010-07-09 05:18:12   12:37:04   Main Door(I/O)  Entry
Dinesh 2010-07-09 17:56:10   2010-07-09 17:55:16   00:00:54   Ground Fl(I/O)  Entry
```

I implemented the view in the most obvious way. You'll need indexes on the holder name, date, and time. You might get better performance by joining the table to itself rather than using these scalar subqueries. Either way, performance on a large data set might not be great. (But you can usually restrict the holder name and date range, which will help.)

---

For Access, you'd use a query more like this, which I copied from SQL view.

```
SELECT IO.holder_name
     , [io_date] & " " & [io_time] AS io_timestamp
     , (select max(io_date) 
        from iodata 
        where holder_name = IO.holder_name 
          and io_date <= IO.io_date) 
          & " " & 
       (select max(io_time)
        from iodata
        where holder_name = IO.holder_name 
          and io_date <= IO.io_date 
          and io_time < IO.io_time) AS previous_timestamp
     , DateDiff("n",[previous_timestamp],[io_timestamp]) AS elapsed_minutes
     , IO.io_gate_name
     , IO.io_status
FROM iodata AS IO
ORDER BY IO.holder_name, IO.io_date, IO.io_time;
```

I took some shortcuts, because I'm at work. I display elapsed minutes instead of elapsed time in an "00:00:00" format. I ignore the null timestamp for the first row.

Comment: The asker tagged this as ms-access.  I'm guessing you've written TSQL here, which won't run as is in jet sql.

Comment: Earlier example is standard SQL, not TSQL. I'll leave it because it's generally useful, and because it took me a while to type.

Comment: +1 Without testing it myself, this looks like it should work.  Of course it would be a much simpler query if the asker has control over the db schema and can combine the date and time columns.

Comment: The above query got the result but how can I retrieve the result based on date choose by the user. For example I need the result between 2010-07-03 to 2010-07-05. Please give suggestion.

Comment: Suggestion? Search Access help for `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

If possible (and I realize it may be waaay too late to do this), I would recommend redesigning your schema.  The following seems to make more sense:

```
HolderName      IOGateName        EnterDT              ExitDT 
Dinesh Kumar    Basement(I/O)     2010/07/09 00:50:05  2010/07/09 00:52:55
Dinesh Kumar    Basement(I/O)     2010/07/09 01:00:07  2010/07/09 01:35:42
Dinesh Kumar    Ground Floor(I/O) 2010/07/09 01:36:37  2010/07/09 01:37:02
```

Notice that while it may look like less data, you are not actually losing any information...just normalizing your structure.

It will take a bit of care on the data entry side.  For instance, you'll need to do UPDATEs in addition to INSERTs.  And you may need to handle nested locations if those are possible (eg, a clean room inside a lab where the entry/exit for the clean room would come between entry and exit events for the lab itself).

All of those things can still be handled with this design and the reporting will be greatly simplified and more efficient.

Answering your original question about the duration spent in a location is now trivial.

Comment: This has nothing to do with normalization; the original data is in 5NF. Your idea assumes a person enters and exits the same door. That's not reliably true in the real world, and it's not even true in the supplied sample data. (Look at the entries beginning at 04:11:54.)

Comment: Then I guess I am confused about what the asker wants.  For the 04:11 Basement Entry what would be the corresponding Exit record?  One could argue that there is an implied Basement Exit when he enters the Ground floor at 05:10.  My schema easily supports that case.

Comment: @Catcall: In his question, the asker specifically asked about the difference between EntryTime and ExitTime.  What your solution provides is the elapsed time between consecutive events.  Since the asker accepted your solution, it seems this is what the asker actually wanted, but it doesn't seem to be what he asked for.

Comment: There might not be a basement exit logged for 04:11--could be an unsecured stairwell or elevator between the basement and the ground floor. (Some electronic locks generate this kind of log file.) Figuring out what the OP needed based on what the OP asked for is typical of requirements gathering. (Which, if I had to sum it up in few words, would be "Trust nothing.") The longer you do this stuff, the better you get at it. It was my 26+ years of database development experience that led me to name the view "suspicious_person_movements". (smile)

Comment: @Catcall:  Well put.  I get this sneaking suspicion that I am learning as much (or more) than I am teaching by answering questions on forums like SO.  And, yeah, I had to re-read the question a couple of times before coming to the conclusion that you had simply inferred the name of your view from the sample data.  Well played ;).